# javascript doesnt work, isnt getting parameters?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know why this isn't working, combination of 2 answers today. I'm just trying to get the parameter passed to show up in alert, everything else works so ignore the url action etc

```
$('#changetopicss').click(function () {
    $('#loadingAjaxs').show();
    $('#flubestext').hide();

    var link = '@Url.Action("Detail", "Topics", new { @id = 304,  @name = "newest", @forum = "all", @page = 0})';

    var dataid = $(this).data(id);
 //       link = link.replace("-1", $(this).data(id));
 //       link = link.replace("-2", $(this).data(shortname));
    window.alert(dataid);
        $('#contentwrap').load(link, function () {
            $('#loadingAjaxs').hide();
            $('#flubestext').show();
            window.history.pushState(null, 'title', '/topics');
        });
    });
</script>

<a id="changetopicss" data-id='@following.Id' data-shortname='@following.ShortName'>@following.Title</a>
```

everything else works, now trying to debug why i cant pass the data-id to window.alert as it wasn't working in url.action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
var dataid = $(this).data('id');
```

A quoted string, not just an identifier.

Comment: pointy do you know how these would be perceived by the controller (string or int etc?)

Comment: They don't exist in the context of the controller. They are executing in the browser javascript engine ....

Comment: they do once i reactivate the comented out lines and put -1 and -2 in the url.action link

Comment: @mxadam I don't know much about how asp.net works, so I can't say.